# How to send the command error output to a variable (error can be occured after nth place) in TCL?

Tags: tcl, expect

I am using following TCL script to configure VLAN's in a router.

```
send "interface vlan 1\r"
expect "*#"
send "commit\r"
expect "*#"
send "interface vlan 2\r"
expect "*#"
send "commit\r"
expect "*#"
.
.
send "interface vlan <n>\r"
expect "*#"
send "commit\r"
expect "*#"
```

After some point of time, once maximum number of VLAN's that can be configured on this router is  reached, it will through a error. it can be at VLAN 16 or  VLAN 32 or VLAN 48.

I want to capture this error output to a variable for further processing. Is there any way to capture this error output to `$expect_out(buffer)`? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Balu P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say if the error occurs on the `interface` command or the `commit`. Something like:

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= 48} {incr i} {
    send "interface vlan $i\r"
    expect {
        "*ERROR*" {
            # specify the error string you want to catch instead of "ERROR"
            set err $expect_out(buffer)
            break
        }
        "*#" {
            send "commit\r"
            expect "*#"
        }
    }
}
```